# DynamoDB: cost implications with more partitions vs items per partition

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

I want to migrate my partition design from having multiple items in one partition to having each spread across partitions.
They're not related, stay the same size and are always pulled individually.

Now I wonder if this might produce increased costs, for example storage wise.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, as you will ultimately be storing the same amount of data.

In-fact you will have a reduced throughput cost as you will be writing and reading smaller items, consuming less capacity.

[This blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/use-vertical-partitioning-to-scale-data-efficiently-in-amazon-dynamodb/) explains the advantages of vertical sharding.